# Apache /Ubuntu server not running WordPress installation, outputting PHP code like HTML

Tags: php, apache, linux

I'm trying to get WordPress running off of a plain Digital Ocean Ubuntu droplet. I'm running Apache, and it serves basic `index.html` files fine, from my `/var/www/html` directory. When I unzip the latest WordPress version from `https://wordpress.org/latest.zip` and place the contents in the `html` directory, it's just serving the PHP code but not running it.

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

I have a MySQL server running on that droplet as well, with the same `wp-config.php` files that I have locally in my `/Sites` directory(same WordPress configuration that works locally). I've `sudo apt-get install`ed mysql, php, and apache2.

Apologies if this is too host-specific, but I feel like its probably a basic misunderstanding of how to get WordPress running off Apache with Ubuntu, rather than anything Digital Ocean related. Also seems like I'm just forgetting to download some package.

Comment: So you mean that Apache is just outputting your php file just like an HTML file?

Comment: yea. i have apache v.2.4.18 and php v.7.0.13, if that makes a difference

Comment: Checkout [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5121495/2488619) answer. It might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple mistake. Needed to make sure I installed the correct php module for apache, which is libapache2-mod-php7.0. I had installed one for a previous version of php.

Comment: But you already said another version of your WordPress is working with php

Comment: It was working locally, on my macbook(should have specified that). The same wordpress install wasn't working on the server. I hadn't configured the remote server correctly.